# Есть ли способ в Xamarin android получить список локальных серверов MS SQL?

Tags: android, c#, sql, sql-server, xamarin

Есть ли способ в Xamarin android получить список серверов MS SQL, находящихся в локальной сети?

`DataTable servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();`

Выдает ошибку:
the requested feature is not implemented

Comment: а разве MS SQL уже умеет запускаться на андроиде?

Comment: MS SQL находится в локальной сети. Телефон к ней подключен по wifi.

Comment: Раз Xamarin  не предоставляет такую возможность - придется искать ручками или просить пользователя. Смотрим на текущий ip и маску, рассчитываем диапазон и начинаем на каждый стучаться.